# Build string from another strings in loop using stringstream

Tags: c++, string, merge, getline, stringstream

I want to build one string from strings that are typed in loop by `getline()`

```
cin >> n;
string all,line;
stringstream ss;    

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ss.clear();
        line.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, line, '\n');
        ss.str(line);
        all += ss.str();

    }
    cout << all << endl;;
```

I expected:

```
input:
2
word
word

output:
wordword
```

Instead of this I get:

```
input:
2
word
word

output:
wordord
```

I can't find solution for that. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the `>>` operator, `getline()` consumes the newline. Your next iteration then `ignore()`s the `w` of the following line.

Just moving the `ignore` out of the loop should produce the desired result.

You're overcomplicating this a bit, though – you don't need to "detour" through a `stringstream`:

```
cin >> n;
cin.ignore();
string all;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    all += line;
}
cout << all << endl;
```

But, you can accumulate the entire thing into a stream, and convert afterwards (which is more efficient):

```
cin >> n;
cin.ignore();
ostringstream all_stream;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    all_stream << line;
}
string all = all_stream.str();
cout << all << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin.ignore()` is ignoring the first character in the second input word. Get rid of it.